# Combining fonts in XeLaTex

Tags: fontspec

I have been able to combine math fonts thus

```
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={"0370-"03FF}]{GFS Baskerville}
\setmathfont[
   range={"0000-"50,"52-"007F}, % minus ()
   Numbers=Lowercase]           % and use Q from main
   {Adobe Caslon Pro}
```

but when I try the same with the main font

```
\setmainfont[Numbers=Lowercase, Mapping=tex-text]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\setmainfont[range={"0041-"007A}]{Wyld}
```

an error occurs

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                                     │
!                                                                                    │
! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown"                                                  │
!                                                                                    │
! The key 'fontspec/range' is unknown and is being ignored.                          │
!                                                                                    │
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.                              │
!                                                                                    │
! For immediate help type H <return>.                                                │
!...............................................                                     │
                                                                                     │
l.23 \setmainfont[range={"0041-"007A}]{Wyld}                                         │
                                                                                     │
?
```

It seems that the range option is unavailable for `\setmainfont`; but why? and is there another way to combine two or more fonts?

Comment: The `range` key and `\setmathfont` are not from `fontspec`, but from `unicode-math`, a separate package entirely.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.

Comment: You can't mix text fonts this way, sorry.

Comment: @Lawrence What would be the use of changing the characters in the ASCII range with another font?

Comment: @egreg, the font I want to use lacks some symbols.

Comment: @egreg Also, it would be nice to pick a single character from a StylisticSet variant. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447690/how-to-replace-a-letter.