# How to replace a letter?

Tags: fonts

When I use font package **FiraSans**

I enter "g", get

[image]

But actually I want to get

[image]

I don't quite understand that FiraSans font has two g forms, but they do exist in "*.otf"

I checked the description and ".sty" file of the package, only found the command to control the numeric style.

If you can not affect the Italian font, then it is better.

Comment: Do you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with the `.otf` fonts or pdfLaTeX with Type 1 fonts?

Comment: If you switch to FiraGO (https://bboxtype.com/), the successor to Fira Sans 4.3, `ss05` controls ‘g’ and only ‘g’, whereas in Fira Sans `ss04` controls both ‘g’ and ‘a’.

Comment: @Thérèse Are the stylistic sets and alternatives of the font families documented anywhere, or do we just have to look it up in a program like FontForge?

Comment: @Davislor Some designers and foundries provide documentation, and others don’t.  FiraGo comes with several PDF files, and those called “Technical_Report*.pdf” dcoument the features.

Comment: @Thérèse Ah! I did look through that document, but I didn't see it until I searched. According to [pages 37–38](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bBoxType/FiraSans/master/Fira_Sans_4_3/Technical%20Report%20PDF/Technical%20Report%20Fira%20Sans.pdf), Stylistic Set 5 ought to work in Fira Sans as well.

Comment: @Davislor But that refers to the final release of Fira Sans, which is newer than the version in TeX Live.

Comment: @Thérèse So, if you upgraded to that, or to Fira Go, SS05 would work.

Comment: Got it working in XeLaTeX, Also enables you to load it through the `firasans` package with all its features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following workaround enables you to change the letter g without also changing the letter a, in the upright font.  First, download the updated version (4.301) of the font files (or at least the ones that are in `TEXMF/fonts/opentype/public/fira` into a subdirectory of your project directory, named `fonts`.

This version contains the substitution you want as Stylistic Set 5.  You can tell `fontspec` to look in your project’s `fonts` directory for Fira Sans and to add this stylistic set on every upright font in the family that it will load in the future.

This will completely remove any ambiguity about which of the several versions of Fira Sans on your hard drive you want to load.

Then, load the `firasans` package and get all its interfaces.  Or load it yourself by the method of your choice.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Requires version 4.301 of the font files to be stored in a subdirectory
% named fonts
\defaultfontfeatures[FiraSans]{
  UprightFeatures = { StylisticSet=5 },
  BoldFeatures = { StylisticSet=5 },
  Path = ./fonts/ }

\usepackage[sfdefault]{firasans}

\begin{document}
Ziggy eats eggs.
\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Sans Stylistic Set 5]

If the package maintainer updates the version of the fonts in the TeX Live distribution, this hack will no longer be necessary. As of TeX Live 2018, it is.

#### Another Approach

The `firasans` package is what you were using before, and has a number of options and support for different font weights.  Since some commenters requested a solution using only `fontspec`, here it is.  This defines the de-facto standard LaTeX2e series names, as defined in the second edition of *The LaTeX Companion* and [The LaTeX Font Installation Guide.](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.pdf#appendix.A](Font)

This version does not support all the weights of the font family, but it does support all the ones that correspond to LaTeX commands in common use, such as `\textlf` and `\sbseries`.  For ordinary use, you might prefer to do what the package does and create a font family that selects relatively lighter or darker weights as its regular and bold.

It does define `\firafamily` for compatibility with `firasans`, but doesn’t declare all the variants that package does.

It is also more future-proof, should the `firasans` package ever change (for example, to load Fira Go).

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Requires version 4.301 of the font files to be stored in a subdirectory
% named fonts
\setsansfont{FiraSans}[
  Ligatures = { Common, Discretionary, TeX },
  Numbers = { Lining, OldStyle },
  Scale = 1.0 ,
  FontFace = {ul}{n}{ StylisticSet=5, Font = *-UltraLight},
  FontFace = {ul}{it}{*-UltraLightItalic},
  FontFace = {el}{n}{ StylisticSet=5, Font = *-ExtraLight},
  FontFace = {el}{it}{*-ExtraLightItalic},
  FontFace = {l}{n}{ StylisticSet=5, Font = *-Light},
  FontFace = {l}{it}{*-LightItalic},
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  UprightFeatures = { StylisticSet=5 },
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  FontFace = {mb}{n}{ StylisticSet=5, Font = *-Book},
  FontFace = {mb}{it}{*-BookItalic},
  FontFace = {sb}{n}{ StylisticSet=5, Font = *-Medium},
  FontFace = {sb}{it}{*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace = {db}{n}{ StylisticSet=5, Font = *-Semibold},
  FontFace = {db}{it}{*-SemiboldItalic},
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  BoldFeatures = { StylisticSet=5 },
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  FontFace = {eb}{n}{ StylisticSet=5, Font = *-ExtraBold},
  FontFace = {eb}{it}{*-ExtraBoldItalic},
  FontFace = {ub}{n}{ StylisticSet=5, Font = *-Heavy},
  FontFace = {ub}{it}{*-HeavyItalic}, 
  Extension = .otf ,
  Path = ./fonts/
]

\let\firafamily\sfdefault
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\firafamily}

% Load other fonts here.

\DeclareRobustCommand\ulseries{\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textul{\ulseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\elseries{\fontseries{el}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textel{\elseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\lfseries{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textlf{\lfseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\mbseries{\fontseries{mb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textmb{\mbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textsb{\sbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\dbseries{\fontseries{db}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textdb{\dbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\ebseries{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\texteb{\ebseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\ubseries{\fontseries{ub}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textub{\ubseries}

\newcommand\eggs{Ziggy eats eggs.}

\begin{document}
\parbox{160pt}{
\textul{\eggs} \textel{\eggs} \textlf{\eggs} \textmd{\eggs} \textmb{\eggs}
\textsb{\eggs} \textdb{\eggs} \textbf{\eggs} \texteb{\eggs} \textub{\eggs}
\textit{\textul{\eggs} \textel{\eggs} \textlf{\eggs} \textmd{\eggs}
\textmb{\eggs} \textsb{\eggs} \textdb{\eggs} \textbf{\eggs} \texteb{\eggs}
\textub{\eggs}}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Does Ziggy eat eggs?]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434273 is relevant if you’re trying to work with newer versions than those in TeX Live.

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks! In practice, I would either stick my own version of the fonts in a project directory and use fontspec’s `Path =` feature to override the (inconsistent) default search paths, or else change the filename, *e.g.* to `FiraSans4.3-Regular.otf`,

Comment: What is the purpose of the `firasans` package?

Comment: @AndreKR I wondered that as well. If one is using `fontspec`, why not just go with `\setmainfont{FiraSans}`? Does the package get you anything extra?

Comment: I added a second solution using only `fontspec`. (And also fixed a bug with bold text in the first MWE.)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using LuaLaTeX and the OTF version of the fonts you can try

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "galt",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {["g"] = 0x210A,}
  }}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={+galt}]{FiraSans}

\begin{document}
gg

\emph{gg}
\end{document}
```

[image: four g's in FiraSans]

Answer (score 10):

This is easy if you use `fontspec` and `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[StylisticSet=4]{FiraSans-Medium.otf}

\begin{document}
Ziggy eats eggs.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

[Thérèse's note](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447690/how-to-replace-a-letter/447694#comment1124736_447690) raises an excellent point: if you do it this way, you change the look of both "a" and "g". Just FYI.

Comment: There is one question: this method has changed the letter a. Can we not change the letter a?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, specifying `StylisticSet` is all-or-nothing – you can't pick and choose characters. But I'm not 100% sure I'm right about that.

Comment: The solution of @moewe doesn’t affect the ‘a’ — this is one great advantage to luatex.