# Use FiraCode ss01 font feature with fontspec and LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, ligatures

How can I set specific stylistic sets of a font (`ss01`, `ss03`, but not `ss02`) with fontspec and LuaLaTeX? For instance, with the [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/How-to-enable-stylistic-sets) font.

This question is not a duplicate of [How to replace a letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447690/how-to-replace-a-letter/447692#447692), and the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447692/213962 targets a different problem: I just need to enable some features, not find and replace their symbols with another.

How can one achieve the same with XeLaTeX?

Comment: Both of the other answers to the linked question show how to enable specific stylistic sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a fast search in the documentation of fontspec for stylistic lead to the following option:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\fontspec{FiraCode}

\&, @, 0.

\fontspec{FiraCode}[StylisticSet={1,3}]

\&, @, 0.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh so I had to omit the "ss0" part, as subsection 3.1.13 says. "Numbers=OldStyle,SlashedZero" enables "onum" and "zero" (dotted zero)

Comment: In my version of the document (which should be the newest one) `3.1.13 Stylistic Set variations — ssNN` describes the syntax quite clear and well.