# Replacing a single letter from another font in mathspec

Tags: xetex, mathspec

I want to replace the letter "f" from a certain font family with "f" from another font family. My current attempt at doing so is the following.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,}
\setmathsfont(Digits){Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Latin)[Uppercase=Italic,Lowercase=Italic]{Old Standard}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{alphabets}{\encodingdefault}{pmn}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{alphabets}{normal}{\encodingdefault}{pmn}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{alphabets}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{pmn}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"66}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Print $f$.
    
    \begin{align*}
        F(x)
             & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)
    \end{align*}\\[1cm]
\end{document}
```

However, it does not produce the math/italic version of "f", only a straight text version. How can I make this italic?

Related questions which do not answer this: [How to replace a letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447690/how-to-replace-a-letter) and [XeLaTeX: mathtools, unicode-math and \text spoil \mathtt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303538/xelatex-mathtools-unicode-math-and-text-spoil-mathtt)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want Minion Pro. For this to succeed you need to declare a font family and assign it a NFSS name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,}
\setmathsfont(Digits){Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Latin)[Uppercase=Italic,Lowercase=Italic]{Old Standard}
\newfontfamily{\minion}{Minion Pro}[NFSSFamily=pmn]

\DeclareSymbolFont{alphabets}{\encodingdefault}{pmn}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{alphabets}{bold}{T1}{pmn}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"66}

\begin{document}

Print $f$.
\begin{equation*}
  F(x) = \sum_{d\mid n}"f(d)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without this approach you got warnings about not existing fonts that are substitute with others.